# Javac inexplicably failing on Hudson

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ant, hudson

Our application is built my Hudson from Ant scripts. In my latest work I've recently included Maven. Now Hudson's build process fails when it reaches the compilation task without any explanation.

**Hudson build:**

```
[echo] Using Maven Repo at ../.maven/repo/
[javac] Compiling 134 source files to C:\Users\administrator1\.hudson\jobs\SAP_RC\workspace\current\classes

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\administrator1\.hudson\jobs\SAP_RC\workspace\current\build.xml:68: Error running C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\javac.exe compiler
```

**Ant script:**

```
<javac classpathref="lib" destdir="${classesDir}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" verbose="true" fork="true" nowarn="true" memoryMaximumSize="320m" srcdir="${srcDir}" includeantruntime="false"  />
```

I specifically included the Maven repo into the classpath, and that's when it fails inexplicably. When I remove the Maven repo the build throws a compilation error complaining that it can't find Maven dependencies. This makes me *suspect* that I'm hitting some classpath length limit.

I did it this way because I'm not sure what is the correct way to include Maven dependencies into the classpath. If there is a better way please tell me and I'll open a new question specifically for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though my wildcard in my fileset was the culprit.

```
<path id="lib">
        <fileset dir="${env.maven_repo}">
            <include name="*/**"/>
        </fileset>
</path>
```

I changed the ** to ***.jar** and the build process is no longer (inexplicably) failing.

```
<path id="lib">
        <fileset dir="${env.maven_repo}">
            <include name="*/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
</path>
```